# How to get "mute" state of all users in the channel? [agora.io]

Tags: agora.io

I have a Voice Call in which I would like to have a little overlay showcasing which users have their audio muted. Is there a callback I can use to know whether users have locally muted their stream?

I have not found a way to do this directly using agora.io's library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the onRemoteAudioStateChanged API: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#a24fd6b0d12214f6bc6fa7a9b6235aeff

Comment: How can I do this in Web SDK? Any resource?